# Getting error as Null check operator used on a null value when variable is made nullable

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, scrollview

In the following code for the scrollcontroller, if i initialise the variable _scrollController as late, then I get issue as
LateInitializationError: Field '_scrollController@1084415195' has not been initialized.
and If i make it nullable, I get
Null check operator used on a null value

```
  class _MyScrollbarState extends State<MyScrollbar> {
       ScrollController? _scrollController;
     ScrollbarPainter? _scrollbarPainter;
    
    Orientation? _orientation;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
    
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    
            _updateScrollPainter(_scrollController!.position);
    
    
        });
      }
```

Comment: ScrollController? _scrollController;

Comment: because you are using  _scrollController without initializing it. you just declared _scrollController as `ScrollController` but you did not initialized inside the initState. take note declaration and initialization is different thing.

Comment: What can i do please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to initialize it in the initState like so:

```html
class _MyScrollbarState extends State<MyScrollbar> {
     late  ScrollController _scrollController;
   late  ScrollbarPainter _scrollbarPainter;
    
   late Orientation _orientation;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        
    _scrollbarPainter = ScrollbarPainter();
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    _orientation = Orientation();

    //after this you can now use it anywhere inside your widget 
    
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    
            _updateScrollPainter(_scrollController!.position);
    
    
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give them a value so that they dont start as Null.
If you give them a default value when you initialize them you should also be able to not use the "?" since now they have a value.

```
ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
ScrollbarPainter _scrollbarPainter = ScrollbarPainter();
```